# WPF ListView grouping with expander via header template?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, expander

All examples I can find for implementing an `Expander` as a group for the `ListView` in WPF do so by defining a new `ControlTemplate` for the `GroupItem` in the `GroupStyle.ContainerStyle` property.

An example of this can be found [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/), and it works as expected.

However it does have the flaw that if you add additional `GroupDescription`s (for multi-level grouping), there is no indentation for the second and subsequent levels like there would be when overriding only the header template and not the container style.

I happened to notice in passing that the `GroupItem` code does appear to have special support for locating an `Expander` control in its template, which (if that's a recursive search) suggests that it might be possible to replace the group style above with a simpler one like so:

```
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="GroupItem">
            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray"
                                   FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22"
                                   Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold"
                                   FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22"
                                   Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
</GroupStyle>
```

ie. the same core `Expander` but expressed in the `HeaderTemplate` rather than the `ContainerStyle`.

This *almost* works -- visually it appears correct, and even has the expected indentation for multiple levels.  But toggling the `Expander` does not actually show or hide the items in the group, so clearly the visual hierarchy is wrong.

I have a few questions:

1. Is there a way to make this work like this?
2. If not, what is the `GroupItem` actually doing with `Expander` detection, if not for this?
3. Sticking with the original `ContainerStyle`, is there a way to keep the natural indentation?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you place `Expander` in the header template, `GroupItem` will not recognize it (if you inspect the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/GroupItem.cs,f580d3d12a1a1df1,references) (in particular [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Helper.cs,951c2d8b543e366b) helper method) you'll see why - it looks for a descendant `Expander`, but with `TemplatedParent` set to the `GroupItem` in question, whereas if the `Expander` is part of the header template, its `TemplatedParent` will be a `ContentPresenter`<sup>*1*</sup>.

Second of all, even if it was recognized, `GroupItem` does not really handle group items visibility - this is done by the `Expander` template (when it's expanded its `Content` is visible, otherwise it is not). `GroupItem` only handles some edge case when UI virtualization is enabled and it's recycled to represent another item (basically it boils down to invalidating measure on the owner `ItemsControl`).

Lastly, the correct approach is to put the `Expander` in the `GroupItem` template (via `GroupStyle.ContainerStyle`). If you blindly follow the referred sample then yes, there won't be any indentation. However, all you need to do is to set desired margin on the `ItemsPresenter`, e.g.:

```
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
</GroupStyle>
```

and voilà! - you've got yourself a nice (and "recursive") indentation.

---

<sup>*1*</sup> *Assuming you do not overwrite the default* `GroupItem` *template*.

Comment: How do you determine the correct Margin to use when the same style is used at multiple hierarchy levels?  (Also, that doesn't indent the expander header itself.)